# Compare data with present date google script

Tags: date, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

Hi i want to compare column with date (i.e "Referral Date" column) [image: image of column]
with present day , here is what i have

```
function newF(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Worksheet');
var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var headers = range.getValues()[0];
  var colIndex = headers.indexOf("Referral Date");
  var today = new Date();
var searchRange = ss.getRange(2,colIndex+1,ss.getLastRow()-1);
for (i=0;i<range.getLastRow();i++){
  var dates = searchRange.getValues();
      if (today.valueOf()>dates.valueOf()){
        updatelFilter()
      } else{
        SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Future Date Error');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem i have is, it throws alert **Future Date Error** irrespective of date in column (Referral Date). Let me know if additional information is required.

**My goal:**

1)if date column (Referral Date) is greater than present date : Throw alert error & should not run `updateFilter`

2)if (Referral Date) is lesser than present date: Run `updateFilter` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

1. `searchRange.getValues()` yields a two dimensional array. So `dates[0][0]` points to a date, while `dates[0]` points to an array.
2. `var dates = searchRange.getValues();` is being called inside the loop repeatedly, when it should ideally be called outside once since the value will not change; calling it inside the loop is costly and redundant
3. `for (i=0;i<range.getLastRow();i++){` the condition can be replaced with `i<dates.length` if point 2 is followed
4. `if (today.valueOf()>dates.valueOf()){` I believe is supposed to have `dates[0]` instead

## Modified Code

```
function newF(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Worksheet');
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
  var headers = range.getValues()[0];
  var colIndex = headers.indexOf("Referral Date");
  var today = new Date();
  var searchRange = ss.getRange(2,colIndex+1,ss.getLastRow()-1);
  var dates = searchRange.getValues().map(d=>d[0]); 

  for (i=0;i<dates.length;i++) {
    if (today.valueOf()>dates[i].valueOf()){
      updateFilter()
    } else {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Future Date Error');
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

## To run updateFilter only if no future dates

Replace the loop with the following -

```
if(dates.some(d => today.valueOf() < d.valueOf())) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Future Date Error');
} else {

  for (let i=0; i<dates.length; i++) {
    updateFilter();
  }
}
```

Comment: THANKS ALOT !! for explanation and code it does the job...but it runs `updateFilter` first and then gives is there way to reverse it, i tried reversing logic but no change

Comment: Do you mean to check whether any dates are in the future before running `updateFilter`?

Comment: Yes exactly, and only run `updateFilter` if there is no future date

Comment: Btw, you could do this using sheet formulae. Select column and right click > Data validation > Criteria > Custom formula is and type (if the first row affected is `A2`), `=A2<=Today()`. Then select reject input.

Comment: I cannot use data validation as i might add/delete columns hence range will differ and modified script throws error first then runs `updateFilter` may be i did something wrong not sure... i replaced from `for (i=0;i<dates.length;i++) {` to end

Comment: @Shiva edited. The rest is a matter of simple for loops and if conditions, can't write ALL your code for you I'm afraid :-)

Comment: THANKS A TON!! made little changes it worked great :-)